# cant change class resource at runtime godot

Tags: class, runtime, godot, gdscript

im making a project for listening to episodes of a podcast as if they're real cassettes. The idea is that some info about the episode shown on the cassette model + it's audio file are stored in a class, then before putting the cassette in the player, being able to change the class resource the cassette takes from with buttons. My problem is that it doesnt let me change it on runtime, just set it on the ready function.
The way the cassette script loads the data:

```
onready var data = preload("res://MAGs/Season1/Ep1.tres")
```

The way im trying to change it:

```
func _ep_select():
    data = load(<different cassette's data>)
```

If its impossible to change it on runtime, what should i use instead of this?

Comment: You should be able to change what the variable holds, and you should be able to load resources at runtime. What happens when the line `data = load(…)` runs? Are you getting any error? Is the line running at all (perhaps at a `breakpoint` or `print` statement to check)? Also, what do you with the variable afterwards (it could be loading the other resource, but you are not using the variable anymore, or what fails is what you try to do with it)?

Comment: Really sorry for not answering sooner. I noticed that even tho i was changing the 'data' variable, i wasnt resetting the text and audio file variables to take from the changed 'data'. Thank you for the help!